# tensorflow image_dataset_from_directory difference from PIL load

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, python-imaging-library

tensorflow version:2.5.0-dev20210301

pillow version:8.1.2

I trained model using API image_dataset_from_directory to load image
and tried to inference image using PIL,

first, I put only one image in my directory.

But I found the return of image_dataset_from_directory doesn't match PIL read

I tried the method of resize are bilinear both,
but the return of tensorflow is float data
and PIL is INT data, and value are completely different.

there is my code and result

```
def load_image_from_tensorflow(self, path):
    validation_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(path,
                                              shuffle=False,
                                              batch_size=32,
                                              image_size=(224,224))
    for image, _ in validation_dataset.take(1):
        img = image
    return img

def load_image_from_pil(self, path):
    img = Image.open(path)
    img = img.resize((224, 224),Image.BILINEAR)
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
    return img
```

tensorflow output:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[186.      , 211.      , 216.      ],
         [185.9576  , 210.9576  , 215.9576  ],
         [185.59598 , 210.59598 , 215.59598 ],
         ...,
         [205.61609 , 225.02011 , 227.80804 ],
         [204.16965 , 223.21207 , 227.08482 ],
         [204.      , 223.      , 227.      ]],
```

PIL output:

```
array([[[[181, 206, 213],
         [181, 206, 213],
         [181, 206, 213],
         ...,
         [204, 222, 225],
         [202, 221, 225],
         [202, 221, 225]],
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use image_dataset_from_directory(path etc   it looks in the directory defined by path and looks for sub directories. It process the subdirectories in alphanumeric order. Then it fetches the files from the sub directories again in alphanumeric order. So when you do take[1] the file you are actually getting may not be the file you think it is. So you are probably comparing two different files . I copied your code but I used my directories. In my class sub directories  my files are named in numerically sequential order using "zeros" padding for the filenames. For example if you have ten files in a class subdirectory and they are named 1.jpg, 2,jpg ... 9.jpg, 10.jpg then data set is returned in the order 1.jpg, 10.jpg, 2.jpg etc. So it is not the order you might expect. Same kind of rule applies to the class sub directory names. If you name the files 01.jpg, 02.jpg .... 09.jpg, 10.jpg they will be returned in that order. So when I ran you code I knew exactly which file would be returned and they do match (for the non decimal valua) when you print out the image with the exception the values are floats for the tensorflow data and integers for the PIL data. I do not know why the tensorflow values are  floats of the form say 188.123 while the PIL value are just 188.

Comment: Thanks for your comment,
in order to avoid this problem,
my directory only put one image.

Comment: Hmm with only1 file it should be the same. Let me look at it a bit more.